How can I identify which "Bootloader" is active between two different operating systems installed on separate SSDs?
I have two SSDs, each with a different operating system installed (Windows 11 and Ubuntu). Both SSDs are connected to the same system, and I want to understand how to identify which bootloader is currently in control when I switch between them. Is there a way to verify or determine which bootloader is being utilized during the startup process?
Are there any tools or command-line utilities in either operating system that can help me check the active bootloader? Any guidance would be appreciated!

You'll be using the Windows bootloader (Windows bootloader manager) whenever you run Windows and Ubuntu's GRUB whenever you run Ubuntu.
Even when you select Windows from the GRUB menu it merely chainloads to the aforementioned Windows bootloader.
With such simple dual-boot scenario this question doesn't make sense, it's straightforward one or the other, end of story. It would be a somewhat interesting question with more than one desktop Linux distro and/or more than one Windows version.
